# Getting white space when converting Bootstrap Columns to act as table using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, css-tables

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row-table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0!important;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.row-t {
  display: table!important;
}
.row-tr {
  display: table-row!important;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  display: table-cell!important;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: none!important;
}
.parent {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-table row-t parent">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">4</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row-t row-table parent">
    <div class="row row-tr">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

> Sorry, this question has been slightly changed to fix a issue, as
>   it wasn't getting Reproduced earlier.

I want my bootstrap columns to have equal height like tables and should be able to vertically align them in middle - this is the workup I have done.

**Try viewing these snippets in Full Screen view - you'll notice ~1px
whitespace on left and right borders in between red and black., I need to remove it, but how? (specially in Google Chrome)**

*and also do let me know, which approach is better for this kind of requirements.*

*is this approach correct?*

**row is display:table;**

```
.row {
    display:table;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.row >[class*="col-"] {
    display:table-cell;
    float:none;
}
```

*or this approach is the correct one?*

**row is display:table-row;**

```
.row {
    display:table-row;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.row >[class*="col-"] {
    display:table-cell;
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: Why r you overriding row class. Why don't you just add **.row > [class*="col-"]{height:100%}**  to your css file.

Comment: `height: 100%;` does only work if the parent element has a fixed height

Comment: @VVK as much as I know, it won't work..

Comment: From my experience `table-row` is not necessary. Option 1 should work.

Comment: @SexyTurnip yeah, even I was using this till today..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyhow, I have found the solution, this problem only occurs on Google Chrome. It needs a slight work-around. 
I had to add `border-collapse:collapse;` to parent element and as had to remove its border property.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row-table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0!important;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row-t {
  display: table!important;
}
.row-tr {
  display: table-row!important;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  display: table-cell!important;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: none!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-table row-t parent">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">4</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row-t row-table parent">
    <div class="row row-tr">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this only hides the leading space - collapse is better but not perfect

Comment: i'm still facing some issues. I still see that white space on my design.even after adding this fix